# Which function is equipollent to “pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock()” and “pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock()” on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, posix

I am modifying a project which run on Window and Linux to build and run it on Mac OS X. Project used two functions:

> pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock()
>   pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock()

But these functions is missing on Mac OS X

> https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/pthread_005frwlock_005ftimedwrlock.html
>
> https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/pthread_005frwlock_005ftimedrdlock.html#pthread_005frwlock_005ftimedrdlock

So i want to ask which function is equipollent to “pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock()” and “pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock()” on Mac OS X ?

Comment: There’s documentation online about how to write a read/write lock. You could just use a mutex instead.

Comment: Thanks @KhouriGiordano but I am implementing MultiReaders, SingleWriter so I cannot use mutex.